# How to get start date and end date from calendar view in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using a bootstrap datepicker in my site. And I want to get start date and end date from a calendar view.

For example :

[image]

As shown in above figure I want to get start date (25/09/2016) and end date (05/11/2016). And similarly for next month. For this I a am trying  below code :

```
function available ()
{
    ....
}
jQuery('#date_field').datepicker({ autoclose: true,beforeShowMonth: available });
```

But it is not working.

How to to that?

Comment: Have read the docs ? if not then [Click Me](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowmonth). I think you are using beforeShowMonth in wrong way.

Comment: Hello @KeyurShah, I am using in correct way, When I use `beforeShowDay` it is working and function executing for every date but not full fill my requirements.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?